# How to add ImageView instead Labels on Axis in AChartEngine?

Tags: android, achartengine

I want to add Image instead of Labels on XAxis, so does anyone know how to do that ?

Thanks in advance.

> Update

I want to do something like the below image.

[image]

Comment: why do you want that?

Comment: I want to do some thing like the attached image.

Answer (score 0):

For this you have to edit source code of `Achartengine` because there is not any direct method for this.

Draw circles instead of small lines . For different colors of the circles , you may have to change few other things .

Change `drawXLabels()` method in `XYChart.java` .

```
protected void drawXLabels(List<Double> xLabels, Double[] xTextLabelLocations, Canvas canvas,
      Paint paint, int left, int top, int bottom, double xPixelsPerUnit, double minX, double maxX) {
    int length = xLabels.size();
    boolean showLabels = mRenderer.isShowLabels();
    boolean showGridY = mRenderer.isShowGridY();
    boolean showTickMarks = mRenderer.isShowTickMarks();
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      double label = xLabels.get(i);
      float xLabel = (float) (left + xPixelsPerUnit * (label - minX));
      if (showLabels) {
        paint.setColor(mRenderer.getXLabelsColor());
        if (showTickMarks) {
//          canvas.drawLine(xLabel, bottom, xLabel, bottom + mRenderer.getLabelsTextSize() / 3, paint);
          canvas.drawCircle(xLabel, bottom + mRenderer.getLabelsTextSize() / 3,3, paint);

        }
        drawText(canvas, getLabel(mRenderer.getLabelFormat(), label), xLabel,
            bottom + mRenderer.getLabelsTextSize() * 4 / 3 + mRenderer.getXLabelsPadding(), paint,
            mRenderer.getXLabelsAngle());
      }
      if (showGridY) {
        paint.setColor(mRenderer.getGridColor(0));
//        canvas.drawLine(xLabel, bottom, xLabel, top, paint);
        canvas.drawCircle(xLabel, top,3, paint);
      }
    }
    drawXTextLabels(xTextLabelLocations, canvas, paint, showLabels, left, top, bottom,
        xPixelsPerUnit, minX, maxX);
  }
```